# Direct effect is negative but non significant; indirect effect is positive but significant

Tags: statistical-significance, mediation

I'm testing a simple mediation model (Model 4 by Hayes, 2018). I have what Baron and Kenny would call a 'full mediation' as results. Paths a and b are positive and highly significant (p < .001). My total effect is also positive but non-significant. What's weird is that my direct effect is negative, although it is also non-significant.

The thing is, even if it is non-significant, it would not make logical sense that X would negatively affect Y. How would this happen? Are there any papers regarding such issue?

Answer (score 0):

> I have what Baron and Kenny would call a 'full mediation' as results.

Please avoid using terms like partial and full mediation. See Rucker et al. (2011, p.367) section titled **"Partial and Full Mediation: Indicators of Practical Importance or Effect Size?"** for why to avoid these terms.

> Paths a and b are positive and highly significant (p < .001).

I'm assuming here that you are referring to the indirect effect ***ab*** and not paths ***a*** and ***b*** individually? After all, the current standard on mediation analysis would require that you conduct the joint significant test of ***ab***.

> it would not make logical sense that X would negatively affect Y. How would this happen? Are there any papers regarding such issue?

Tough to say. It could be measurement error, sampling fluctuation, or omitted variable. Alternatively, there could be a theoretical basis for why the direct and indirect effects are opposite in signs. An example given by Zhao et al. (2010) is that condom availability (X) reduces the perceived risk of sex (M). Meanwhile, perceived risk of sex is negatively linked to the level of sexually transmitted diseases (Y). Here paths a & b are both negative (so indirect effect *ab* = positive). However, condom itself also reduces the level of sexually transmitted diseases, so the direct effect is *positive*.

See Zhao et al. (2010) discussion on **"Competitive mediation"** -- note that this article uses path ***c*** to describe the *direct* effect instead of the *total* effect like most mediation papers. Another useful paper to read is Shrout & Bolger's (2002, p.430) section titled **"Suppressor Variable Processes"**

**References**

Rucker, D. D., Preacher, K. J., Tormala, Z. L., & Petty, R. E. (2011). Mediation analysis in social psychology: Current practices and new recommendations. Social and personality psychology compass, 5(6), 359-371.

Shrout, P. E., & Bolger, N. (2002). Mediation in experimental and nonexperimental studies: new procedures and recommendations. Psychological methods, 7(4), 422.

Zhao, X., Lynch Jr, J. G., & Chen, Q. (2010). Reconsidering Baron and Kenny: Myths and truths about mediation analysis. Journal of consumer research, 37(2), 197-206.

Answer (score 0):

There are some cases, however, in which the mediated effect turns out to be larger than the total effect, that is a⋅b>c. It is clear that this implies that c′ and a⋅b have different signs. For instance, one can have c=10, c′=−1 and a⋅b=11. There is nothing wrong with that, but let see when that happens and what it implies.

There are two cases of interest: 1) In the first case, the most common one, the direct effect is very small, often not significant. 2) In the second case, the total effect is very small (or not significant), whereas the mediated effect is substantial and significant. These two cases have very different interpretations.

Seemingly odd results in mediation analysis
(Marcello Gallucci)
https://jamovi-amm.github.io/notes_inference.html